# Visual Basic with Oracle 11g using REF CURSOR NOT working

Tags: vb.net, oracle, recordset, ref-cursor

I am using Visual Basic 6 to connect to Oracle 11g.
Yes, I can successfully connect to the database.
The problem is to receive the recordsets from the database.
I have created an oracle package like below:

Package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_BASECODE AS

TYPE T_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR;

--// customer
PROCEDURE CustomerCode (
    I_CUST_CODE          IN VARCHAR2
    , I_CUST_NAME        IN VARCHAR2
    , customer_cursor    OUT T_CURSOR
);

END PKG_BASECODE;
/
```

Body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_BASECODE AS

--// customer
PROCEDURE CustomerCode (
    I_CUST_CODE          IN VARCHAR2
    , I_CUST_NAME        IN VARCHAR2
    , customer_cursor    OUT T_CURSOR
)
IS
    BEGIN
    OPEN customer_cursor FOR
    SELECT  CUST_CODE      AS KEYVALUE
            , CUST_NAME    AS DATAVALUE
    FROM    CUSTOMER_MASTER
    WHERE   CUST_CODE      LIKE I_CUST_CODE || '%'
    AND     CUST_NAME      LIKE I_CUST_NAME || '%'
    ORDER BY CUST_NAME ASC
    ;
    END CustomerCode;


END PKG_BASECODE;
/
```

It works great with C#.
I have already tested.

Now I have my Visual Basic 6 source codes below:

```
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim input1 As ADODB.Parameter
Dim input2 As ADODB.Parameter
Dim output1 As ADODB.Parameter
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = tmpDB_Total

    .CommandText = "PKG_BASECODE.CustomerCode"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("I_CUST_CODE", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, "")
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("I_CUST_NAME", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, "")
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("CustomerCode", adVarChar, adParamReturnValue)
    Set rst = .Execute
End With

If Not rst.BOF And Not rst.EOF Then
    Do Until rst.EOF
        Debug.Print rst.Fields(1).Value & "," & rst.Fields(0).Value
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
```

And the connection source is below:

```
tmpDB_Total.Open "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;" _
                 & "Password=mes123;" _
                 & "User ID=mes;" _
                 & "Persist Security Info=True;" _
                 & "Data Source=stmdev;"
```

And I receive an error something about parameters.
The error message is written in Korean language, so I cannot write straight away.
Please understand me.
Could anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got an extra parameter in there. Just don't try to append anything for that third parameter, and it should work. Note that you will need to set `Cmd.Properties("PLSQLRSet") = TRUE`

Comment: I didn't know how to accept your answer. Now I found it how to. Anyway, thanks a lot.